# Ios app is using more than 50 GB of space xcode and Ad Hoc installation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storage, gcdwebserver

I have recently provided a link for my client to install an ios app on their IPAD through AD Hoc build.
Everything is working fine for 2 weeks, but we see that the app has already consumed more than 50 GB in usage and I am not sure why and what is causing this issue..?
I am using GCDWebserver and running a local webserver and using webkit to show the webpage.

I have ran the app on emulator and saw that the documents folder where the files are stored does not increase in size but the /var/db/diagnostics folder keeps increasing by 1MB.

I have disabled GCDWebserver logging by Setting setting log level to 4. I have added OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable.

Is there any other things I need to check and why is that .tracev3 log files size keep increasing...? Any help would be greatly appreciated..!

Comment: Did you check all the application folders : cache, library,… ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked all the folders except this /var/db/diagnostics folder, no other folder's size increases.